# CMakeLists - Make does not find header files

Tags: c++, header, include, point-cloud-library

I have the following CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(PointCloudComparator)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)

set(PCL_DIR "/usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake")
set(PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/pcl-1.7")
set(PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS "/usr/lib/")


include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} "/usr/include/eigen3" "include")
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (segmentator src/segmentation.cpp include/segmentation.h)
target_link_libraries (segmentator ${PCL_LIBRARIES} 
${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES} 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_visualization.so" "/usr/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_features.so" "/usr/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_search.so" "/usr/lib/libpcl_filters.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so")

add_executable (comparator src/comparator.cpp include/comparator.h 
include/segmentation.h)
target_link_libraries (comparator ${PCL_LIBRARIES} 
${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} 
${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES} "/usr/lib/libpcl_visualization.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so" "/usr/lib/libpcl_features.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so" "/usr/lib/libpcl_search.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_filters.so" "/usr/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so" 
"/usr/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so")
```

But, when I try to compile my code, I get the error:

```
CMakeFiles/comparator.dir/src/comparator.cpp.o: In function `main':
comparator.cpp:(.text+0x3313): reference to 
`region_growing_segmentation(std::string)' not defined
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

region_growing_segmentation(std::string) is a function declared in segmentation.h and defined in segmentation.cpp. Eclipse actually knows where the function is but when I try to run make it just simply cant find it. Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: CMake version 2.6 does not support `target_link_libraries`. The above CMake file requires version 2.8.11 at minimum. That said, I'd recommend you to bump it up to 3.6 or 3.7 and [start writing modern CMake](https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building two separate executables (`segmentator` and `comparator`). Each executable is made from one single source file and one single header file. That is what you say with the `add_executable` commands. The source files used by a single `add_executable` command is *not* shared with any other executable target you create.

If you have common code that should be shared between the two programs, then you should put it in a separate source file that you add to each executable (add the new common source file to the `add_executable` command). Or create a library target that is linked with the two executables.

Comment: So I just add lines like:
add_library(mylib SHARED src/segmentation.cpp src/comparator.cpp)
set_property(TARGET mylib PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION mylib.a)

And mylib into both target_link_libraries?

Comment: works like you said, I just added a library target linked to both .cpp files
. thanks